# Advantages of carbon wires for igniters?

Tags: wire, spark

I was troubleshooting the spark ignition on a gas oven and was surprised to discover that the ignition wire, which carries the high voltage to create the spark, had a carbon core instead of metal.

Why are carbon wires used for high voltage igniters/spark plugs?  The best explanation I could find is from https://www.magnecor.com/magnecor1/truth.htm and talks about the higher wire resistance reducing EMI.

Is reducing EMI the primary/only purpose of using carbon wires?  If so, why is this approach used instead of the (seemingly more simple) metal wire with a series resistor?  Also, are carbon wires still commonly used in new equipment, or are they a thing of the past?

Answer (score 2):

Yes EMI is the primary reason and it is also cheaper than wire with a long epoxy molded carbon resistor rated for 10kV